# Duda grafico de violines

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos con R. En este caso estoy representando una gráfica de violines con mis datos, y tengo una duda. **(1) No sé cómo hacer para que me ordene los violines de izquierda a derecha de menor media a mayor media**. Y en algún paper he visto que se puede **(2) trazar una línea horizontal que representa la media** de las medias de todos los violines, esto también  me gustaría hacerlo, pero no sé cómo lo hacen.

Y otras dudas más sobre formato, **(3) ¿cómo podría elegir otra gama de colores que diferenciara más los violines entre sí?** **(4) Hay algún repositorio donde pueda elegir diferentes paletas de colores para probar?**

Codigo:

```
q <- ggplot(matrix2, aes(x=data1, y=data2)) + 
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(0, 0.5, 1, 4, 5, 10, 13, 50, 100, 300)) +    
  geom_violin(aes(fill = factor(data1))) +               
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=2, color = "black") +  
  labs(title="Poner título", x="xx", y="yy") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +        
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),  
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, size = 7, color="black"),       
    axis.line.x = element_line(size = 0.2),       
    axis.line.y = element_line(size = 0.2),       
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "grey50", linetype = "dashed", size = 0.2), 
 )       
q
```

Comment: Hola Juan, ¿podrías poner algún ejemplo de tus datos? Eso facilitaría mucho responder. Podrías usar `dput(head(matrix2))` y pegar la salida en consola.

Comment: Buenas, gracias por el interés. Para data 1 hay más de doscientos nombres diferentes, que se repiten cada uno de ellos 28 veces, y para cada vez que se repite, tiene un data2 diferente, y eso es lo que estoy representando

Comment: data1 data2
ABL1 0
ABL1 4.856679391
ABL1 2.005817875
ABL1 1.457003817
ABL1 2.571183207
ABL1 2.266730226
ABL1 0.703111762
ABL1 0
ABL1 0
ABL1 1.260868688
ABL1 0
ABL1 0.236058224
ABL1 0
ABL1 0.944232897
ABL1 1.309666353
ABL1 14.04967967
ABL1 0
ABL1 0
ABL1 0
ABL1 0.439297633
ABL1 0
ABL1 0
ABL1 1.365941079
ABL1 3.000694361
ABL1 1.10193566
ABL1 1.306404419
ABL1 2.521737376
ABL1 3.181059547
ALKBH2 0
ALKBH2 0
ALKBH2 0
ALKBH2 0.687143544
ALKBH2 0
ALKBH2 2.619103743
ALKBH2 0
ALKBH2 0
ALKBH2 4.69268762
ALKBH2 0
ALKBH2 0
ALKBH2 1.558597418
ALKBH2 0
ALKBH2 0

Comment: ¿Y cuantos grupos o "violines" esperas mostrar en el gráfico? ¿los 200 que mencionas?

Comment: en realidad son tres columnas;
data 1 (con 240 tipos)
data 1a (con 28 clases diferentes, para cada una de esas clases hay analizados 240 tipos)
data 2 ( con frecuencias para cada data1)
entonces lo que me interesa es hacer 28 violines, uno por cada clase, y para cada clase hay 240 tipos cada uno con su frecuencia.
Lo que quiero es que se ordenen los 28 violines, de menor a mayor media, de izquierda a derecha,y después sacar una línea horizontal que represente la media de las medias de todos los violines.

Comment: Y si puede ser alguna función para que los violines pueda representarlos con otros colores que se diferencien más entre si.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

una disculpa por la demora. 
Ya veo que tenés respuestas para la mayoría de tus dudas, cortesía de jbkunst y Patricio Moracho. De todos modos agrego una respuesta más amplia y detallada que cubre cada uno de los puntos y explica alguna peculiaridades de `ggplot`

Con la función `tribble()` creo un `data.frame` al que llamo `foo`. 
Este tiene la estructura correcta para hacer un gráfico de violines:

- `data1` es una variable categórica que identifica grupos. Por cada uno de estos grupos se graficará un violín.
- `data2` es una variable numérica continua cuya distribución se presenta cada violín.

  ```
  library(tidyverse)

  tribble(
  ~data1, ~data2 ,
  "ABL1",  0 ,
  "ABL1",  4.856679391,
  "ABL1",  2.005817875,
  "ABL1",  1.457003817,
  "ABL1",  2.571183207,
  "ABL1",  2.266730226,
  "ABL1",  0.703111762,
  "ABL1",  0,
  "ABL1",  0,
  "ABL1",  1.260868688,
  "ABL1",  0,
  "ABL1",  0.236058224,
  "ABL1",  0,
  "ABL1",  0.944232897,
  "ABL1",  1.309666353 ,
  "ABL1",  14.04967967,
  "ABL1",  0,
  "ABL1",  0,
  "ABL1",  0,
  "ABL1",  0.439297633,
  "ABL1",  0,
  "ABL1",  0,
  "ABL1",  1.365941079,
  "ABL1",  3.000694361,
  "ABL1",  1.10193566,
  "ABL1",  1.306404419,
  "ABL1",  2.521737376,
  "ABL1",  3.181059547,
  "ALKBH2", 0,
  "ALKBH2", 0 ,
  "ALKBH2", 0 ,
  "ALKBH2", 0.687143544,
  "ALKBH2", 0 ,
  "ALKBH2", 2.619103743,
  "ALKBH2", 0,
  "ALKBH2", 0 ,
  "ALKBH2", 4.69268762,
  "ALKBH2", 0,
  "ALKBH2", 0 ,
  "ALKBH2", 1.558597418,
  "ALKBH2", 0 ,
  "ALKBH2", 0) -> foo   # le asigno el nombre foo.
  ```

Con `ggplot2` podemos hacer un gráfico de violín básico en dos líneas, siempre que tengamos datos con una estructura similar a la anterior. 
En este caso uso los nombres de columna del `data.frame` que creé más arriba.

```
ggplot(foo, aes(x = data1, y = data2)) + 
  geom_violin()
```

## Respuestas a cada pregunta.

1. `ggplot2` ordena a los violines de acuerdo con el orden del factor que controla al eje *x*. En términos técnicos **hereda** ese atributo. Para cambiar el orden de los violines tenemos que cambiar el orden de ese factor. Si queremos dar un orden arbitrario podemos usar la función `factor()` y reodenar ahí. Para este caso, en el que queremos ordenar por la media de otra variable podemos usar función `fct_reoder()` de la librería `forcats`, que automatiza el proceso de reordenar un factor de acuerdo a otra variable numérica o un sumario de esa variable. La segunda línea del código transforma a `data1` en un factor ordenado por la media de cada grupo de `data2` y le da un orden descendente.
2. Para trazar la línea que une a los puntos de las medias de cada grupo/violín es necesario tener calculadas las medias. Por eso usamos `stat_summary()` y no directamente `geom_line()`. Con esto le indicamos a `ggplot` que calcule las medias y grafique en una línea que una a esos valores. Es necesario pasar el argumento `group = 1` para que `ggplot` sepa como queremos que se unan los puntos que cortan las líneas.
3. Para colorear los violines se mapea el atributo `fill` a alguna variable, en este caso a `data1`. A mí me parece redundante colorear los violines, porque ya están claramente etiquetados en el eje *x*, pero que se puede, se puede.
4. `fill =` indica a `ggplot` que queremos colorear los violines, pero no que colores queremos usar. Eso se puede especificar con diferentes funciones de la familia `scale_fill_*`.

   - `scale_fill_manual(values=c("color1", "color2"))` nos permite controlar manualmente los colores.

     - El largo del vector creado con `c()` debe tener el mismo largo que la cantidad de violines/grupos en `data1`.
     - Los colores se llaman por nombres y acá http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf encontrás una paleta de colores y nombres. `ggplot` los recibe como una cadena de caracteres, así que cada color debe ir entrecomillado.
     - Hay otras formas de indicar los colores, por ejemplo con código hexadecimales.
   - `scale_fill_brewer()` para usar las paletas brewer.
   - En http://www.datavis.ca/sasmac/brewerpal.html encontrás un resumen un poco feo pero bastante práctico de las paletas disponibles.
   - La sintaxis para la paleta `Set3` sería `scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3")`

## Código.

```
library(forcats)  
foo %>%                                                                        # Comienzo la cadena de funciones con los datos. 
  mutate(data1 = fct_reorder(data1, desc(data2), fun=mean)) %>%                # Reordena el factor data1, que controla el orden de los violines. 
  ggplot(aes(x = data1, y = data2, fill = data1)) +                            # Mapeo lo atributos visuales a mis datos.
  geom_violin () +                                                             # La línea de código más simple hace lo más difícil. 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", group = 1) +                           # Genera una línea que une las meidas de cada grupo. 
  #stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=2, color = "black") + # Redundante con la línea.
  scale_y_log10(breaks = c(0, 0.5, 1, 4, 5, 10, 13, 50, 100, 300)) +           # para transformar *y* a una escala logarítmica. En el código de la pregunta, no sé para qué está.  
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +                                         # Especifico los colores para el relleno. 
  labs(title= "Gráfico de Juan M.", 
       x = "Factor o variables discreta", 
       y = "Variables contínua cuya distribución presentan los violines", 
       fill = "Etiquetas de la variable \n de relleno. Redundante.")
```

## Resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Primero que nada armaremos un ejemplo más simple que el tuyo para que sea más fácil y comprensible, un `data.frame` con solo 3 grupos  de datos al azar con medias distintas en cada uno, en tu ejemplo sería `data1` y `data2` repectivamente:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(10)
df<-data.frame(x=rep(c("Grupo1","Grupo2","Grupo3"),100,each=100), 
               y=c(rnorm(100, mean = 3, sd = 1), 
                   rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 1),
                   rnorm(100, mean = 1, sd = 2)
               )
)

head(df,10)
        x        y
1  Grupo1 3.018746
2  Grupo1 2.815747
3  Grupo1 1.628669
4  Grupo1 2.400832
5  Grupo1 3.294545
6  Grupo1 3.389794
7  Grupo1 1.791924
8  Grupo1 2.636324
9  Grupo1 1.373327
10 Grupo1 2.743522
```

Comencemos con un gráfico de violín sencillo

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_violin() +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=2, color = "black")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tres grupos o violines ordenados alfabéticamente y un punto en cada uno para indicar el valor de la media. Veamos ahora tus preguntas:

#### (1) No sé cómo hacer para que me ordene los violines de izquierda a derecha de menor media a mayor media.

Para esto son muy útiles los Factores, estos tienen internamente un orden determinado por los `levels`, cuando se crean automáticamente al crear un `data.frame`, el orden es alfabético, por lo que simplemente debemos ordenar los `levels`:

```
orden <- aggregate(y ~ x, df, mean)
orden <- orden[order(orden$y),]
df$x <- factor(df$x, levels = orden$x)
```

- Con `aggregate(y ~ x, df, mean)` agrupamos por `x` y calculamos la media de cada una de ellas
- Con `orden <- orden[order(orden$y),]` ordenamos por la media calculada de cada grupo en orden ascendente, si quisieramos orden descendente: `orden[-order(orden$y),]`
- Por último reordenamos el `factor` por el orden deseado: `df$x <- factor(df$x, levels = orden$x)`

Ahora simplemente hay que graficar, el código sigue siendo el mismo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora sí los grupos ordenados por la media

#### (2) trazar una línea horizontal que representa la media

Para esto, aprovecharemos el objeto `orden` que hemos creado, este simplemente tiene las medias ordenadas de cada grupo:

```
       x        y
3 Grupo3 1.057504
2 Grupo1 2.863451
1 Grupo2 9.905037
```

Para graficarlas como líneas, agregaremos un [`geom_hline()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.1/topics/geom_hline) de la siguiente forma:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_violin() +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=2, color = "black") +
    geom_hline(data = orden, aes(group = x, yintercept = y), color = "red")
```

Obtenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### (3) ¿cómo podría elegir otra gama de colores que diferenciara más los violines entre sí?

Tienes dos opciones, o defines manualmente los colores o usas alguna función que te retorne una paleta del tamaño necesario para los grupos a graficar. De cualquier forma deberás establecer el parámetro `fill` para  `geom_violin` y relacionarlo con cada grupo: `geom_violin(aes(fill=x))`, con esto decimos que el "llenado" de color de cada violín lo determina la variable `x` (en tu caso `data2`). Luego simplemente hay que establecer los colores:

Manualmente:

```
scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9"))
```

Desde una paleta ya definida en R:

```
scale_fill_manual(values=terrain.colors(3))
```

Nota: Hay varias ya disponibles `rainbow()`, `heat.colors()`, `terrain.colors()`, `topo.colors()`, y `cm.colors()` que puedes evaluar. El funcionamiento es similar, le pides una cantidad determinada de colores y retornaran un vector con los mismos. También dispones de `colorRampPalette()` que permite "generar" paletas a partir de ciertos colores límites que le pases: `colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow", "green"))`

Pero además dispones de múltiples paletas para elegir, producto de los gustos y necesidades de los usuarios que las comparten como paquetes, por ejemplo: `RColorbrewer` que ya ofrece funciones para integrarse a `ggplot`:

```
library("RColorBrewer")
scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")
```

Veamos un ejemplo final:

```
library("RColorBrewer")

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_violin(aes(fill=x)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=2, color = "black") +
    geom_hline(data = orden, aes(group = x, yintercept = y), color = "red") +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### (4) Hay algún repositorio donde pueda elegir diferentes paletas de colores para probar?

No hay ningún repositorio específico para paletas, puedes buscar estas por lo medios habituales para buscar cualquier paquete de `R`, lo que sí hay una muy completa recopilación de paletas en [este sitio](https://github.com/EmilHvitfeldt/r-color-palettes).

Mas info:

- [Quick start guide - R software and data visualization](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-violin-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization)

Answer (score 0):

Quisiera proponer otra alternativa al punto uno, a través del uso del paquete `forcats` (anagrama de factors, que viene en el paquete tidyverse) el cual viene con muchas funciones para trabajar con factores, en particular, `fct_reorder` reordena factores, segun una funcion aplicada de otro valor. En este caso el la función de la media y la columna es `y`. El uso sería `x = fct_reorder(x, y, mean)` ver detalles más abajo.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(10)

df <- data.frame(x = rep(c("Grupo1", "Grupo2", "Grupo3"), 100, each = 100), 
  y = c(rnorm(100, mean = 3, sd = 1), rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 1), rnorm(100, 
    mean = 1, sd = 2)))

library(tidyverse)

df <- mutate(df, x = fct_reorder(x, y, mean))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_violin() +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=2, color = "black")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchísimas gracias por vuestra ayuda, me ha sido tremendamente útil!!!!!